# wget command not found in jenkins but runs Ok from unix

Tags: unix, jenkins, solaris

I put this PATH=$PATH:/bin:/opt/swe/bin on jenkins and wget command works fine but when I remove this or commented out, it doesn't work and generated the following error:

/var/jenkins/workspace/ORANGE_HOST_ATT/ORANGE_HOST_ATT.sh: line 119: wget: command not found

I am using solaris 10 machine for build and when I "type wget" in unix it says wget is an alias for /opt/swe/bin/wget. How can I set this wget command so that I don't have to use PATH=$PATH:/bin:/opt/swe/bin in each and every jenkins configuration.

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Do you start Jenkins via system or commandline? Do you use a tomcat or do you start it with `java -jar jenkins.war`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure environment variables for master in `$JENKINS_URL/configure` or for a slave in `$JENKINS_URL/computer/SLAVENAME/configure`. Check the box "Environment variables" and fill in key-value pairs.

Comment: It helped to find the issue. Checked the Path varialble and the one I need wasn't there so added and issue resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using the full path for `wget`, you could in one the `PATH` directories setup a symbolic link to wget.

Whatever `PATH` directory suits your needs. Perhaps /usr/local/bin (I think this exists in Solaris but it's been a while).

```
ln -s /opt/swe/bin/wget /usr/local/bin/wget
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. will try this. it is /usr/bin/wget in solaris.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the Alias for the user that is used to run Jenkins, not for your user

Comment: yes I logged in solaris with the same user id that runs in jenkins but making alias doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

But what do you do for built-in shell commands like this csh one?

```
% which unsetenv
unsetenv: shell built-in command.
```

In Jenkins log file I get:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/blah@tmp/durable-7c938f97/script.sh: line 2: unsetenv: command not found
```